# Volume of solids of revolution- How to take the limits

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

Hello all,

Can anybody please help me in understanding that in the example why they have taken the limits of $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi$?

Thanks

Comment: you have a shape that's symmetrical along x axis so it's enough to rotate this shape $\pi$ radians to get complete solid.

Comment: So, if I had a shape which was symmetrical about y-axis and I am rotating it around x-axis then?

Comment: Then you would need to rotate 360 degrees

Answer (score 0):

First, to answer your question as to the limits. Using $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ will give the shaded region in the figure. However, I believe there is an error in the page you copied. Specifically, the equation for the volume shown applies to rotation about the $y$-axis, not the stated rotation about the $x$-axis. You can see the details in my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456078/what-is-the-volume-of-a-body-of-revolution-in-polar-coordinates).

The integration should be (with help of WolframAlpha)

$$V=\frac{2\pi}{3}\int_0^\pi (1-\cos\theta)^3\cos \theta~d\theta=-\frac{5\pi^2}{4}\approx -12.337$$

The negative value is because of the $\cos\theta$. It can be rectified by taking $\theta\in[\pi,0]$. I have verified this (negative) result numerically.